# Cannot found the route without the app_dev.php

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, virtualhost

When I go to my website like this :

`example.com/` or

```
example.com/app_dev.php
```

That works fine.

But when I try to go to a different route like

```
example.com/api/route/option
```

I got an error 404, however when I go to

```
example.com/app_dev.php/api/route/option
```

That is working fine.

This is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is my virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin my_mail
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/web/
        DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Got an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: have you looked at http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html ? seems like you dont have override enabled for your web folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your virtual host file doesnt enable overrides meaning your `.htaccess` file isnting being read. Try adding this to your virtual host file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/example/web/>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

You may also want to look into other setup options as documented here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html